# Enable/Disable one Account sync only

Tags: tasker

Is it possible, using Tasker (or Tasker Plugin), to enable/disable the synchronisation for a specific account/app only, without changing the sync status for any other account?

e.g. only change the Sync enabled/disabled state "Sync Inbox" on my work Google Apps account.

I have been using Tasker and the Synker plugin, but this changes all the Accounts which existed when you setup the Tasker Plugin (e.g. if you change the settings from the Account Settings later, the next time the Tasker task runs the Synker plugin resets your changes) - unless those accounts didn't exist when you configured the plugin in which case it ignores them.

Comment: Can you precisely explain to us what problem you're trying to solve by asking this? It may be doable but at least we should know what we're trying to help you with so that we try to find alternatives means as well.

Comment: Basically I want to have multiple trigger actions which don't require a complex set of Synker profiles setup.
 i.e. the syncs would be turned on or off as follows (and left unchanged when the condition stops being met)

- Connect to SSID CorpNet - Work Email on, Personal Email Off
- Connect to SSID "#CityFree", Turn work off, Personal On (i.e. left office)
- Connect to Bluetooth "Pure DAB" turn all email syncs off
- Disconnect from "Pure DAB" B/T Turn all email On (except work which should be left alone)

Then when I no longer want Play Music auto synching respect my change in Settings

Comment: (Sorry for the formatting, It's ignoring the Markdown)